# Convert character to date format and then compute difference in days

Tags: r, datetime, lubridate

I know this question has probably been answered in different ways, but still struggling with this. I am working with a dataset where the dates format for date1 is `'2/1/2000', '5/12/2000', '6/30/2015'` where the class() is `character`. And the second column of dates date2 in the format  `'2015-07-06', '2015-08-01', '2017-10-09'`  where the class() is  `"POSIXct" "POSIXt"` .

I am attempting to standardize both columns so I can compute the difference in days between them using something like this
`abs(difftime(date1 ,date2 , units = c("days")))`

I have tried numerous ways in converting the first date1 into the same class using strtime, lubridate etc. What's the best way to move forward for me to be able to standardize both and compute the difference in days?

Answer (score 2):

**sample data**

```
x <- c('2/1/2000', '5/12/2000', '6/30/2015')
y <- as.POSIXct(c('2015-07-06', '2015-08-01', '2017-10-09'))
```

**code**

```
#make both posixct
x2 <- as.POSIXct(x, format = "%m/%d/%Y")

abs(x2 - y)
# Time differences in days
# [1] 5633.958 5559.000  832.000
```